# Karate test - any way to do an "or" match in "match each"?

Tags: karate, web-api-testing

I have something like the following. Is it possible to get karate to do an "or" match for `foo` and `bar`?

Meaning - `foo` starts with `fooStartWithChar` OR `bar` starts with `barStartWithChar`

```
And match each response ==
    """
    {
      foo: '#? { _.charAt(0) == fooStartWithChar}',
      bar: '#? { _.charAt(0) == barStartWithChar}',
    }
    """
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes plain old JS (+Java) is your friend:

```
* def response = [{ foo: 'aa', bar: 'bb' }, { foo: 'ax', bar: 'by' }]
* def isValid = function(x){ return x.foo.startsWith('a') || x.bar.startsWith('b') }
* match each response == '#? isValid(_)'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
* def nameStartsWith = function(x) { return x.foo.charAt(0) == fooStartWithChar || x.bar.charAt(0) == barStartWithChar}
And match each response == '#? nameStartsWith(_)'
```